# How to write an annotation to check if a property is null?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core, data-annotations

I have this code that I am writing all the time in the OnGet method of my .NET Core Page code-behind:

```
[BindProperty(SupportsGet = true)]
public string ContextId { get; set; }

public void OnGet()
{
    if (ContextId == null) { throw new FileNotFoundException(); }
}
```

I have heard that it is possible to write an annotation that I can put on the Property itself instead of having to check if it is null in the OnGet method. How can it be done?

Comment: What would you expect this annotation to do? Prevent the property from being set to null?

Comment: throw an exception that I catch and deal with

Comment: There's nothing like that that I'm aware of. Where did you hear that it exists? C# 8 will have nullable reference types that will help with this kind of thing.

Comment: I believe it can be done with Aspect Orientated Programming. I know of two products that claim to do it. https://www.postsharp.net/ and https://github.com/Virtuoze/NConcern.